# Sequelize MySQL Migration - unique to false

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a migration in Sequelize and MySQL, which sets the unique attribute to false. This is my approach so far:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
          await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "name", {
              type: Sequelize.STRING,
              allowNull: false,
              unique: true,
          });
          await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "email", {
              type: Sequelize.STRING,
              allowNull: false,
              unique: true,
         });
    },

 down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
          await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "name", {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            unique: false,
      });
          await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "email", {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            unique: false,
   });
  },
};
```

The up migration works like charme, the down migration works for allowNull, but not for unique attribute. I am new to Sequelize so I am wondering, what is going wrong here. Can someone help me out?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequelize has "removeConstraint" method, using which you will be able to remove the constraint for the attribute.

```
public removeConstraint(tableName: string, constraintName: string, options: Object): Promise
```

Actually, if you don't specify the "constraintName" in creating, it should be of the form "attributename_unique_key".

Please try using this way

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "name", {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    });
    await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "email", {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "name", {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    });
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint("users", "name_unique_key");
    await queryInterface.changeColumn("users", "email", {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    });
    await queryInterface.removeConstraint("users", "email_unique_key");
  },
};
```

For more information please check the documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeConstraint)

Comment: Hi Sir. Thanks a bunch. I realy struggle with the docs. Unfortunately your approach leads to an error:  name_unique_key on table users does not exist. I might have to specify a constraintName, but I dont know how I could do it with sequelize.

Comment: Can you please try to change "name_unique_key" -> "name" and "email_unique_key" -> "email"

Comment: If you got the same issue please try to change "name_unique_key" -> "name_UNIQUE" and "email_unique_key" -> "email_UNIQUE"

Comment: Hi, thanks once again for helping me out. Indeed the version without _unique_key worked. Thanks a million.